# Halal meat butchers European countries

Tags: meat

Salam alaykom,
In European countries, can we consume halal meat from (Muslim) butchers that say it is halal (written on the store, and said verbally) it is they who assume the responsibility, or we have to trace the source to verify that it was slaughtered in the Islamic way (in the name of God, not electrocuted ...) because when asked, the answer is most often "we get it from halal slaughterhouses, we do not slaughter it ourselves".